# Can't use await in update method of apollo mutation

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to update cache to trigger rerender of UI but it seems that the `update` method on apollo mutations does not work correctly if you use `async/await`

```js
mutation({
  variables: {
    ...
  },
  update: async (cache, responseFromMutation) => {
    ...
    const someFunctionResult = await someFunction()
    proxy.writeQuery({...}) // this writes to cache but doesn't trigger rerendering of UI. If we take out the `await` it works.
  }
})
```

Any ideas?